# Docker: баг bash консоли

Tags: bash, docker

При выполнении команды `docker exex -it CONTAINER /bin/bash` заходим внутрь контейнера и открывается bash. Однако, наблюдается следующий баг. При попытке ввода строки, превышающей n-ое количество символов, курсор перебегает на начало текущей строки и дальнейший ввод символов затирает существующие. После этого при попытке выполнить предыдущие команды из истории ввода консоль графически "ломается". Можно ли это как-то вылечить?

Comment: [и дальше по ссылкам](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33794)

Answer (score 0):

проблема зарыта где-то в глубинах программы *docker*: при команде *exec* запускаемому процессу размеры терминала передаются чаще всего некорректно.

---

#### пример.

в хост-системе у меня вот такого размера создаются терминалы при запуске эмулятора терминала для *x-сервера*:

```
$ stty size
27 91
```

если запустить *bash* с помощью *docker-а*, то всё в порядке:

```
$ docker run --rm -it debian:9 bash
root@c1afd369fe6c:/# stty size
27 91
```

а если теперь запустить ещё один процесс *bash* в том же контейнере, то размеры (чаще всего) будут некорректны:

```
$ docker exec -it $(docker ps --format "{{.ID}}" -n 1) bash
root@c1afd369fe6c:/# stty size
0 0
```

программа *bash* умеет обходить некорректность, подставляя дефолтные 24x80:

```
root@c1afd369fe6c:/# echo $LINES $COLUMNS
24 80
```

но, понятно, что если у вас размер терминала другой, то и получается то, что описано в вопросе: строки длиннее размера терминала некорректно «заворачиваются».

---

#### средства обхода этого бага.

1. можно изменить размеры терминала. обычно ведь используется иксовый эмулятор терминала, значит мышкой потяните любую его сторону/угол, уменьшив или увеличив размер терминала (это не играет роли). или разверните окно, а потом опять верните прежний размер (это обычно можно и без мышки сделать).

   в описанном средстве самое главное — это отсылка сигнала *winch* (*window resize signal*, см. `$ man 7 signal`). его можно послать процессу и без реального изменения размеров терминала:

   ```
   $ docker kill --signal="WINCH" идентификатор-контейнера
   ```

   но, увы, у меня это не сработало (предполагаю, что он отсылается только основному запущенному в контейнере процессу).
2. если знаете реальные размеры терминала, то их можно задать вручную (подставьте свои актуальные цифры):

   ```
   root@c1afd369fe6c:/# stty rows 27 cols 91
   ```

---

ссылки с полезной информацией:

- [Strange terminal behaviour inside docker #33794](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33794)
- [Container create or start should accept height/width params #10341](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10341)